# Django tinyMCE is not defined

Tags: django

I'm working on adding tinyMCE to the admin change_form and returning the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined

It looks like the source has loaded correctly in the developer tools. I'm not sure what's causing the error.

From `change_form.html`

```
{{ media }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.1.6/jquery.tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
  mode: "textareas",
  theme: "simple"
});
</script>
```

Comment: try `tinymce.init({`

Comment: I tried that. It didn't work either.